# How to acheive this in reports and Dashboard?

Tags: reporting, dashboard, custom-reports

I have a requirement to create a report and dashboard . the Requirement is "need a report that shows the % of the email cases that we respond to within 24 hours.  That time clock would stop when an agent accepts the case and begins work on it."

This is when a email case comes in , if the Case owner changes from automated Username to a Particular user than it will be consider as Responded.

Please Advise.

Comment: For this requirement, Have you computed a field to capture how much time it has taken to respond?

If not it has to be, like Capture the date/datetime to calculate the difference of time in hours. And in report you can filter the records to display If the differnece time is below or equal to 24hrs.

Comment: @Praveenkumar I have a workflow that will update the Field name first response with Date and Time . Im new to Salesforce itself . Hence unable to find way how to calculate that % of cases in Reports

Comment: Let me know if your requirement is different to what I have answered.

Comment: @Praveenkumar  currently the workflow will update the Time and Date when the agent changes the owner name. Will that work, or i should calculate the how much time it took for the agent to change the owner name from the time of case is came in.

Comment: @Praveenkumar I have created a workflow that will populate the date and time if the agent changes the owner name field. However the requirement for me is the time should capture only the first acceptance by the agent. as per my workflow it says whenever it is created and edited. So in a day the owner name is changed multiple time the field will update the time with the last edited time. Not the first response. Is there a way to acheive this

Comment: Create  a checkbox, say "Workflow Fired" on creation it would be unchecked(false), make it true in workflow while updating the date & time, And in your workflow have a criteria that only if that checkbox is false trigger the workflow, this you can run it only once.

Answer (score 2):

Go for Summary Report and follow the steps to create a formula field to display the percentage you require.

Create a custom summary formula

```
1. Go to the report type category, then double-click Add Formula.
2. Enter a unique name to the formula as you want it to appear on your report.
3. In the "Description" field, enter a brief description about the formula.
4. From the "Format" picklist, select Percent.
5. Under "Decimal Places," select the number of decimal places to be displayed.
6. Select the Display Area where the calculated formula should be displayed – select Grouping1 to calculate percentage according to rows.
7. Build your formula:
To display the percentage of fields by grouping at a summary level, select the RowCount to consider total number of rows in each grouping and use the formula structure PARENTGROUPVAL(summary_field, grouping_level)
Complete Formula:  RowCount / PARENTGROUPVAL(RowCount, GRAND_SUMMARY)
```

Source Link: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000193514

Comment: @Praveenkumar  what should be the Summary field , Is it the field that display the total hours it takes for first response?. If yes than should we need to use IF condition in the report formula to find the % of Email cases that were responded back within 24 hours.